# Does Poco Data Support Multiple Query String?

Tags: odbc, poco-libraries

I use Poco::Data (ODBC to be explicit) and it works great for single query string. But I wonder If it supports running Multiple query Strings. Something like:

`UPDATE Table1 SET col1=2 WHERE id='ugali'; DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE boom='kaboom';`

I know I can just tokenize string and run individual queries under a single transaction but wanted to know if Poco supports that already. Docs are quiet about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported, but it depends on the backend whether it will work - not all back-ends and versions support it, some back-ends were tested. For examples, see [SQLite](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.7.8/Data/SQLite/testsuite/src/SQLiteTest.cpp#L2544), [Oracle stored procedure](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.7.8/Data/ODBC/testsuite/src/ODBCOracleTest.cpp#L566) and generic [ODBC multiple results](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.7.8/Data/ODBC/testsuite/src/SQLExecutor.h#L495) test.